# NSTableView setting the sort column?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableView with multiple columns. clicking each of the columns sorts by the column like in iTunes. However when the tableview first loads the rows are unsorted and no tablecolumn is highlighted or displaying the up/down indicator image. I'm wondering if theres a simple way I can programmatically set the column the table is sorted by and set the indicator image on startup.

The only solution I can think of is using [NSTableView setIndicatorImage: inTableColumn:] and [NSTableView setHighlightedColumn:], but that makes it so that clicking on the header doesnt highlight the column. I would rather not have to use tableView:mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn: and rewrite the whole click on header to sort thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might try setting your sort discriptor.

```
- (void)setSortDescriptors:(NSArray *)array


- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) windowController
{
   [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:windowController];
   NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"order" ascending: YES] autorelease];
   [oTable setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
}
```

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/May/msg01434.html

Comment: @Kaili where would this go? would I place this in a subclass of NSTableView

Comment: Hmm It's been years since I have done iOS programming haha but, it looks like you want to put that in your controller since the method that does the magic is windowControllerDidLoadNib, I mean I guess you could put it anywhere that has access to the table view and a subclass would probably work just fine.